Homomorphic Max For Two Distances
I have a interesting geometric problem involving distances on a finite plane. I'll provide the unencrypted mathematical background and proof and after that pose the question as it pertains to HE.
Given:

Four points: (X1,Y1), (X2,Y2), (X3,Y3), and (X4,Y4)
We need to compare: Distance((X1,Y1), (X2,Y2)) < Distance((X3,Y3), (X4,Y4))
Only the max function can be used (no squares, square roots, addition or subtractions
The actual distances need not be preserved but the inequality must be preserved

Proof:
Let's define a function F that uses only max operations:
F(X1,Y1,X2,Y2) = max(max(X1,X2), max(Y1,Y2))
Proof that F maintains the order of distances:

F(X1,Y1,X2,Y2) represents the maximum coordinate value among the two points.
While this doesn't directly represent the distance, it provides an upper bound for the coordinates of both points, which correlates with the distance between them.
For any two points (A,B) and (C,D):
max(|A-C|, |B-D|) ≤ max(max(A,C), max(B,D))
The left side of the inequality in step 3 is the L∞ norm (Chebyshev distance) between the points, which preserves the order of Euclidean distances.
Therefore, if F(X1,Y1,X2,Y2) < F(X3,Y3,X4,Y4), then:
max(|X1-X2|, |Y1-Y2|) ≤ F(X1,Y1,X2,Y2) < F(X3,Y3,X4,Y4)
This implies: Distance((X1,Y1),(X2,Y2)) < Distance((X3,Y3),(X4,Y4))
Conversely, if Distance((X1,Y1),(X2,Y2)) < Distance((X3,Y3),(X4,Y4)), then:
max(|X1-X2|, |Y1-Y2|) < max(|X3-X4|, |Y3-Y4|)
This implies: F(X1,Y1,X2,Y2) < F(X3,Y3,X4,Y4)

Thus, we have proven that:
F(X1,Y1,X2,Y2) < F(X3,Y3,X4,Y4) if and only if Distance((X1,Y1),(X2,Y2)) < Distance((X3,Y3),(X4,Y4))
Example:
Let's consider four points with integer coordinates:

P1: (1, 1)
P2: (4, 5)
P3: (0, 0)
P4: (7, 7)

We want to compare:
Distance(P1, P2) < Distance(P3, P4)

Max approach:
F(X1, Y1, X2, Y2) = max(max(X1, X2), max(Y1, Y2))

F(P1, P2) = F(1, 1, 4, 5) = max(max(1, 4), max(1, 5)) = max(4, 5) = 5
F(P3, P4) = F(0, 0, 7, 7) = max(max(0, 7), max(0, 7)) = max(7, 7) = 7
Since 5 < 7, our max approach suggests that Distance(P1, P2) < Distance(P3, P4).

Euclidean approach:
Distance = √[(X2 - X1)² + (Y2 - Y1)²]

Distance(P1, P2) = √[(4 - 1)² + (5 - 1)²] = √(3² + 4²) = √25 = 5
Distance(P3, P4) = √[(7 - 0)² + (7 - 0)²] = √(7² + 7²) = √98 ≈ 9.899
Since 5 < 9.899, the Euclidean approach confirms that Distance(P1, P2) < Distance(P3, P4).
The Homomorphic Encryption Problem:
I am looking for a HE scheme that supports at least the max function that would allow me to encrypt all X,Y values into (E(X),E(Y)) such that the inequality between two distances might be ascertained without ever decrypting.

You should clarify what "distance" means. The most natural interpretation is the Euclidean distance, namely $d_2((X_1,Y_1), (X_2, Y_2))^2 = (X_1-X_2)^2+(Y_1-Y_2)^2$. Your instance that only "max" is used makes it seem like something like the $\ell_\infty$ distance might be more appropriate though, namely $d_\infty ((X_1, Y_1), (X_2, Y_2)) = \max(|X_1-X_2|, |Y_1-Y_2|)$, though the computation of this (in plaintext) still obviously involves subtraction.

Your $F$ doesn't work. Consider (7,7),(7,8) which are distance 1 and (0,0),(6,6) which are at distance $6 \sqrt{2}$ (or distance 6 in $\ell_\infty$ norm), but these pairs give $F$ values 8 and 6, respectively.
